# How to redirect subdirectory only to a new domain?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

How to redirect subdirectory & its links **from like:**

```
mydomain.com/forums/
mydomain.com/forums/linkh.php?blahblkahblahblha?
```

**to:**

```
mydomain.newforums/
mydomain.new/forums/linkh.php?blahblkahblahblha?
```

but keeping the root **mydomain.com** accessible normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you implement a redirection rule that gets applied to that base URL:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?forums https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,R=301,L]
```

That should should get implemented in the http server's host configuration of the original domain. If you do not have access to that (read: if you are using a really cheap hosting provider), then you can implement the same rule in a distributed configuration file (".htaccess") which should get placed in the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory of that http host.

It is a good idea to start using a `R=302` *temporary* redirection. And to only change that to a `R=301` *permanent* redirection once everything works as desired. That saves you the hassle of caching issues with early clients.

Comment: I have access to htaccess & root and it worked perfectly. Thank you very much!!

Comment: You should prefer the actual http server's host configuration over distributed configuration files for a whole bunch of reasons.